# alfresco workflow webscript permissions

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti, alfresco-webscripts

The "task-instances" webscript uses the current users permission to show those task which they are entitled to see. The "ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS" are able to see all the tasks for all users.

I was hoping to display all task to all users and don't want to add everyone to the "ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS" for obvious reasons.

I have tried "http://192.168.0.10:8080/alfresco/service/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin" to get and admin ticket but unfortunately all the code is run in the browser so anyone can see the admin password using dev tools.

Is there a way that I can add all the users to a group that would give them the correct permission to see all tasks without all the other privileges that go with being an sysadmin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write a custom webscript, and use a `RunAs` block inside that to query as admin?

Answer (score 2):

No, the admin permissions are not granular. You are either an admin or you are not. @gagravarr made a good suggestion which is to write your own web script that returns the same data. You can wrap your code in a RunAs block, or you can configure your web script to run as admin, like this:

```
<authentication runas="admin">user</authentication>
```

Obviously, if you do that, any authenticated user will be able to invoke that web script, so be careful what you decide to put in there.

I believe this runas attribute can only be used in web scripts loaded from the file system (rather than loaded from the repository).